# Not Able to accessing URL Parameters in oracle apex application/page process

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am using `Oracle apex 5`,`oracle database 12c`

I have successfully configured `oracle apex 5` with `oracle DB 12c`.

My requirement is to accessing `username` and `password` from `url` and use it as `login credentials`.

But I am not able to get username and password from url in apex processes.
I am tried below stuff:

URL : `f?p=136:1:::::PX_USER,PX_PWD:shree,itdev`

I accessing like :PX_USER and :PX_PWD

but that's not working for me.If any other method is there for accessing parameters in prcessing then please suggest me

Comment: Don't pass sensitive data (such as passwords) in a URL.

Answer (score 2):

Let's hope this is just for educational purposes only. Showing username and password in a URL is not very safe...

If you call an Apex page like this:

```
URL : f?p=136:1:::::PX_USER,PX_PWD:shree,itdev
```

This means that the value "shree" is assigned to page item PX_USER and the value "itdev" is assigned to PX_PWD.

The standard way to name items in Apex is to use the page number. So, create hidden page items P136_USER and P136_PWD and call the page like this:

```
URL : f?p=136:1:::::P136_USER,P136_PWD:shree,itdev
```

The values should be accessible now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using them in SQL/PL/SQL? If you are trying to just set values with them on the page (such as giving another value it as the default value or output them in an html-region), then you have to reference the values such as &PX_USER.

The ending dot is sometimes very important.

And as Rene wrote, make sure they are decalred page-items. If they are, your naming convention is unorthodox. Do adopt the P_name style.